# Cannot build an installer for a CocoaApp (Xamarin.Forms) on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, cocoa, visual-studio-mac

I have been trying to build a simple installer from a newly created template from Visual Studio for Mac.

```
New Project > Cocoa App
```

Nothing fancy really.

I can run the app in debug mode, but as soon as I enable the **Create Installer Package** option, it won't build.

```
Options > Build > Mac Build > Packaging : Create installer package (checkbox)
```

I always get this error:

`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Mac/Xamarin.Mac.Common.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "productbuild" exited with code 134. (MSB6006) (InstallerAttempt01)`

I am using the latest Visual Studio Mac, and the latest Xamarin.Forms versions.

So, I must be missing something, and I don't really know what right now, as I can't find any info on this topic anywhere.

Comment: Under which license option are you using it?

Comment: If you're referring to VS, I'm using Enterprise

Comment: Do you update the other projects to use the same version of the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package ?

Comment: Yes, everything uses the latest version. A collègue that has a Mac running with Intel was able to build a pkg. On my M1, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to confirm that this is a bug, me and one more developer have confirmed it.

You can upvote or comment here so that it may be fixed quicker: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/13197

Update: Apple is expected to fix this problem in the new version of macOS/XCode